# How to add a new [key] => [value] pair after a specific Associative Key in an Assoc Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array_splice() for associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783089/array-splice-for-associative-arrays)
>   [How to add an array value to the middle of an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149437/how-to-add-an-array-value-to-the-middle-of-an-associative-array)

How can I add a new `[key] => [value]` pair after a specific Associative Key in an Assoc Array in PHP ?

For example, let's say we have an array called `$fruits`:

```
array {
   [apple] => 1
   [banana] => 3
   [orange] => 4
}
```

How can I add `[plum] => 2` to `$fruits` so that it appears after the `[apple]` key but before `[banana]` key ?

Thanks.

Comment: In this example, it looks like you want to sort the array in ascending order by the values, maintaining the index, aka `asort`. http://us.php.net/asort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably need to use `array_splice()` to cut the array into two pieces, and then recreate the array with `array_merge()` - Try this nifty function I just whipped up.

Live Sample: http://codepad.org/gGm5C1od

```
<?php
   $orig = array(
       "apple" => 1,
       "banana" => 3,
       "orange" => 4,
   );

   $orig = InsertKeyValuePair($orig, "plum", 2, 1);
   var_dump($orig);

   function InsertKeyValuePair($arr, $key, $val, $index){
      $arrayEnd = array_splice($arr, $index);
      $arrayStart = array_splice($arr, 0, $index);   
      return (array_merge($arrayStart, array($key=>$val), $arrayEnd ));
   }

?>
```

Comment: @DaveRandom: Good catch on that edit. Thanks.

Comment: Invalid Edit by Sandeepan Nath: `/**
         * @desc adds an array value to the middle of an associative array 
         * @param Array $arr - array on which to insert
         * @param string $key - key name to be given to the newly inserted element 
         * @param mixed $val - value for the newly inserted element 
         * @param int $index - at which sequence number? to insert the new array value into the original array  $arr
         */         `

Comment: what was wrong in the edit? please explain @nonnb. May be the sentences could be improved though ...

Comment: @SandeepanNath Editing a Q or A should be minor things like formatting or grammar, not adding to the answer or making comments (use your own answer, or add a comment for this). However, because your edit seemed to contain good advice, it would have been tragic to have lost your edit, hence I pasted it below the post. As you can see, Dutchie has rolled back his answer.

Comment: Ok, its clear now. So, it was "Invalid" in that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is serial number(or something else) of fruits based on there name 
for eg to find  serial number of apple you will use fruits['apple'] then it doesn't matter where a particular element in array exists and if you really want to do it your own way then you can use array_splice() function 
Here's a nice tutorial 
http://www.ferolen.com/blog/insert-into-add-element-to-array-at-specific-position-php/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming associative keyed arrays have a predictable order is not good design.  If you want enforced order, you should mandate it in your design.  For example key the array by the order number, then write custom functions to retrieve data by fruit name.

If you keep assuming keys have a natural order, one day you will run into a scenario where the order may not be as you expected it, and you will have broken functionality.