# How to random insert one line in db return array, and don't miss and row?

Tags: php, loops

I have 6 line per page layout, I try to select 5 rows in database return, and in layout I hope it can be insert 1 line ad html structure in random  position. How to solve it?

example layout:
`| db_array_row 1 | | db_array_row 2 | | db_array_row 3 | | db_array_row 4 | | db_array_row 5 | | ad |`
or
`| ad | | db_array_row 1 | | db_array_row 2 | | db_array_row 3 | | db_array_row 4 | | db_array_row 5 |`

below is what i tried but it will miss one line in db return rows only replace it

```
<?php 
$row_counter = 0;
$random_ad_index_1 = rand(1, 6);

foreach($db_array as $db_array_row) {
  if ( $row_counter == random_ad_index_1) {
    echo 'ad';
  }

  echo $db_array_row['id'];

  row_counter++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add an example or improve your explication.

Comment: like below example, I try to insert random new line in foreach loop

Comment: if you commented out these lines   if ( $row_counter == random_ad_index_1) {
    echo 'ad';
  } do you get all 6 rows?

Comment: no db_array_row 5 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

Demo : http://codepad.org/915y4V2y

#### Output :

```
0. db_array_row 1 
1. db_array_row 2 
2. db_array_row 3 
3. db_array_row 4 
4. db_array_row 5 
ad
```

#### PHP :

```
$db_array = Array("db_array_row 1", "db_array_row 2", "db_array_row 3", "db_array_row 4", "db_array_row 5"); 
$row_counter = 0;
$random_ad_index_1 = rand(1, count($db_array));

do {
  if ($row_counter == $random_ad_index_1)
    echo "ad \n";
  
  if (!isset($db_array[$row_counter])) // last
    break;

  echo "$row_counter. {$db_array[$row_counter]}  \n";

  $row_counter++;
} while ($b = isset($db_array[$row_counter]) || $row_counter == $random_ad_index_1);
```

## Learning

See [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function.

```
<?php
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 3, 0, "purple");
// $input is now array("red", "green",
//          "blue", "purple", "yellow");
?>
```

Similar : [How to add an array value to the middle of an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149437/how-to-add-an-array-value-to-the-middle-of-an-associative-array)

Comment: is there anyway do something in loop, not change data

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ad_index = rand(1, sizeof($rows));

foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {

    echo $row['id'];

    if ($i == $ad_index)
        echo 'ad';

}
```

Comment: it seems still just replace it not insert

Comment: this will be still replace and less 1